# Setup in python a function of Bessel functions that can be both integrated and differentiated

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy, bessel-functions

I need to setup a user defined function `ILTintegrand(u, t, r, b, a)` for `integrand = (j0(ur)*y0(ub) - y0(ur)*j0(ub)) / (j0(ub)*j0(ub) + y0(ub)*y0(ub)) * np.exp(-a*t*u**2) / u`,
where j0 and y0 are the Bessel functions of the first and second kind, respectively.

Then I need another user defined function `ILTintegral(t, r, b, a)` for the integral of `ILTintegrand` in `u`, bewteen 0 and infinity.

But then I also needed differentiating `ILTintegral` with respect to `t` and `r`, to check that a partial differential equation was satisfied (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480235/inverse-laplace-transform-of-bar-p-d-frack-0-sqrts-r-dsk-0-sqrts)).

---

For the integration, I could do this using in `ILTintegrand` the Bessel functions from `scipy` with

```
from scipy.special import j0, y0
```

and then integrating in `ILTintegral` also with `scipy` with

```
from scipy import integrate
intg_pair = scipy.integrate.quad(ILTintegrand, 0, np.inf, args=(t, r, b, a))
```

But then I could not differentiate this wrt `t` or `r`.

---

When trying to integrate with `sympy` (so I could later use `sympy.diff`), using in `ILTintegrand`

```
from sympy import besselj, bessely
```

and then in `ILTintegral` with

```
intg = sympy.integrate(integrand, (u, 0, sym.oo))
```

the calculation was never completing.

---

**What are possible ways of achieving my objective?**

**Related**:

1. [Differentiating a Bessel function with Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75187185/differentiating-a-bessel-function-with-lambda)
2. [Bessel function integral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72876647/bessel-function-integral)
3. [How to calculate derivative and integral of the bessel functions in PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658237/how-to-calculate-derivative-and-integral-of-the-bessel-functions-in-python)

**TL;DR**

On my way of debugging the integration with sympy, I tried with shorter integrands, and changing the limits of integration to [0,1].
I found that

```
integrand = besselj(0, ur)
f = sym.integrate(integrand, (u, 0, 1))
```

works reasonably (though still slower than with scipy, I wouldn't know what happened if I had to evaluate this many times);

```
integrand = (besselj(0, ur) * bessely(0, ub) - bessely(0, ur) * besselj(0, ub))
f = sym.integrate(integrand, (u, 0, 1))
```

throws a long error report with two call stacks of many nested functions related to the computation of `meijerg`, like

```
...
ValueError: 0.302500000000000 is not an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...
ValueError: expecting ints or fractions, got 0.302500000000000 and 1/2
```

and from

```
integrand = (besselj(0, ur) * bessely(0, ub) - bessely(0, ur) * besselj(0, ub)) \
    / ((besselj(0, ub))**2 + (bessely(0, ub))**2)
f = sym.integrate(integrand, (u, 0, 1))
```

towards the final destination, none of the integrations finished.

Comment: Could you provide representative numerical values of the parameters? If so, I can suggest an answer; I'd just like to be able to test it first.

Comment: @MattHaberland - I will check on this and get back to you.